# Can I use DBCC CHECKIDENT for resseding identity column in a table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbcc

I create a table variable with an identity column in my script, I want to reseed this column. Can I use below script?

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tableVariableName, reseed, @NewStartSeedValue)
```

Comment: Have you tried and tested this?  What happened?  Or have you checked Books Online?

Comment: I can't find any thing about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reseed a table variable's identity column, you would need to use a temp *table* instead.
Depending on what you want to do, the ranking functions (`row_number()`) may be of use.